# seed for different numpy functions

Tags: python, numpy, random

```
    a = (np.random.rand(10) > 0.1).astype(int)
    b = np.random.binomial(1, 0.9, 10)
    c = np.random.choice([0, 1], 10, [0.1, 0.9])
```

There are at least 3 different ways in `numpy` by which I can get an array of 0 and 1 (the ones are added with a certain probability p (p=0.9 in example)). When I use `np.random.seed(1)`, the certain method always returns the same array. However, all the above methods create different arrays even with the same seed. Is this happening because they all have different PRNG algorithms or just some of them are not affected by `np.random.seed(1)`?

Comment: Does each method always create the same arrays as previous runs of that method, when given the same seed? In other words, are they just different from each other but still self-consistent?

Comment: It's because they perform different calculations using the random number stream in order to choose the values.

Comment: Yes, they are self-consistent and different from each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different approaches use the stream of pseudo random numbers in different ways, which is why they do not result in the same samples, even if you seed the generator the same way prior to each sample.

This may be clearer by considering an additional approach (used for variable `b` below).

```py
np.random.seed(1)
a = (np.random.rand(10) > 0.1).astype(int)
np.random.seed(1)
b = (np.random.rand(10) < 0.9).astype(int)
```

Both these approaches will generate ones with probability `0.9`, and they draw the same underlying numbers when calling `rand` (since they're seeded the same). If for example, `0.02` is sampled from the call to `rand`, then the corresponding element in `a` will be `0` and the corresponding element in `b` will be `1`. This is analogous to the differences you're observing when using other approaches to generate the samples.